# Is UIPanGestureRecognizer discrete or continuous?

Tags: ios, uikit

I find this doc a bit confusing:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer

Specifically, the top of the doc says it's discrete:

> A discrete gesture recognizer that interprets panning gestures.

Then the following description says:

> A panning gesture is continuous. It begins (UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) when the user moves the minimum number of fingers allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) enough distance for recognition as a pan. It changes (UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed) when the user moves a finger while pressing with the minimum number of fingers. It ends (UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) when the user lifts all fingers.

So which is it? discrete or continuous?

My understanding is that discrete recognizer only calls callback action only when it's recognized (e.g. Swipe), but continuous recnogizers calls the callback action when it's moved as well. So pan gesture should be continuous. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first link DonMag posts in his answer, [About the Gesture Recognizer State Machine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/about_the_gesture_recognizer_state_machine),

It explains that **discrete** gesture recognizers fire/fail once, then reset. **Continuous** gesture recognizers can go into a loop, returning a state of UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed as the user moves their finger.

### Edit:

I think @OMGPOP figured out what's going on. It looks like The word "discrete" in the sentence "A discrete gesture recognizer that interprets panning gestures" should be "concrete". That must be a typo.

Supporting that idea is the fact that the description of the base `UIGestureRecognizer` class says "UIGestureRecognizer: The base class for concrete gesture recognizers." The `UIGestureRecognizer` is the **abstract** parent class of **concrete** classes like `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: What does the "discrete" mean as a term of language?

Comment: I start to suspect that this is a typo and the intended word is "concrete". Because they put "discrete" to not just pan, but all gesture recognizers

Comment: @OMGPOP I bet you're right. That makes a lot more sense. `UIGestureRecognizer` is an abstract superclass and classes like `UIPanGestureRecognizer` are concrete subclasses. Do you want to post that as a separate answer, or would you mind if I edit my answer to suggest that (giving you credit of course.)

Comment: Further supporting the idea that the word "discrete" in the sentence "A discrete gesture recognizer that interprets panning gestures" should be "concrete" is that the description of `UIGestureRecognizer` says "UIGestureRecognizer: The base class for **concrete** gesture recognizers."

Comment: Editing is fine. I think i will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is mainly a "terminology" thing.

A `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is *discreet* in that it doesn't begin on touch... it enters a state of "possible." It only generates a `.began` event after the touch has moved enough distance for it to be recognized as a Pan. After that, it is *continuous* as it sends `.changed` events as the touch is moved.

You may find it helpful to review these Apple's docs (among others):

- [About the Gesture Recognizer State Machine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/about_the_gesture_recognizer_state_machine)
- [Implementing a Custom Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer)
- [Implementing a Discrete Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_discrete_gesture_recognizer)
- [Implementing a Continuous Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_continuous_gesture_recognizer)

Although... you probably only need to know the "down-and-dirty" if you are, in fact, implementing your own gesture recognizer.

Comment: Your links are excellent. The first one defines the terms quite well. However, it explicitly says "A gesture recognizer always starts in the UIGestureRecognizer.State.possible" So your statement that pan gesture recognizers are discrete because they enter a state of possible seems wrong.

Comment: I agree with Duncan that this seems wrong. I also do not understand why "it's called discrete in that it doesn't begin on touch"

Comment: Yeah - I was trying to look at it from a logical point of view... probably should have just referenced the docs in a comment (without my attempt to rationalize Apple's contradictory / ambiguous language).